# Automated theorem proving PhD

Tags: soft-question

I'm looking for a university where I can do doctoral studies in automated theorem proving / computational algebra. Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: Step 1:  find recent papers on your subject of interest using Google scholar or MathSciNet.
Step 2:  identify institution of authors of these papers.
Step 3:  write authors individually by e-mail and ask this question.

Comment: Make sure that you give more motivations than simply asking for a PhD position. Show that you are genuinely interested in their research and explain **why** you like this particular area. I periodically receive generic applications for a PhD with me from people who just do not even know what I am doing so I consider such emails as spam and never bother to reply. I will always reply to someone with good reasons to apply with me though (even if I do not have any available position).

Comment: I always like to study mathematics from the perspective of automated reasoning. I have never been good at solving math problems in a certain time but I always thought that the process of solving a problem can be automated.